# How can make a list duplicate records in list of records and How to send emails to that list at a time

Tags: apex, email, duplicate-management

I have a list of users. Users are nothing but contacts.

Comment: Hi Chris, please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). If you post what you've written so far and where you're stuck, the more likely it is that someone will respond to your question with an answer you'll find helpful. Posting requests to write code for you generally get closed.

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT***
Looking over your update, I can give some more info about next steps. As I mentioned above, you'll want to do some research into the [Schedulable batch apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm) classes so you can have this whole process run automatically every day. Once you've created that, you can insert the code you have into it. So now that you've gotten your User List (usersToUpdate) in the schedulable, you can do something similar to this to get the list of emails you want to send out:

```
List<Id> accIds = new List<Id>();

for(User u : usersToUpdate){
    accIds.add(u.Accountid);
}

List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id, Primary_Admin_Contact__c FROM Account WHERE Id In : accIds];

Set<Id> adminIds = new Set<Id>();

for(Account a : accounts){
    adminIds.add(a.Primary_Admin_Contact__c);
}

List<User> adminsToEmail = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id IN : adminIds];
```

That should give you a list of Users that are admins of the Accounts that you need to notify. After that, you're going to want to make an [Email Template](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_emailtemplates.htm&language=en_US) and send an email to contacts though that.

Once you have all this set up it will run daily and send emails to all the admins where their users haven't been logged in for 150 days.

Comment: I've updated my question. I hope you got my point.

Comment: @chris I've updated my answer accordingly. Hopefully this helps

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to accomplish this is **by implementing the Schedulable batch apex class**.
See this [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5646/scheduling-emails-in-apex)
This job will run on daily basis.

This will check for the contacts which have not logged in for 150 days.

You have to query all the account(You can filter them by applying some filter) in the start

then in the execute method you can grab the contacts associated with them(You can pass only one record of account to execute if the number of contacts are larger in number) and their you can check which contacts have not been logged in.

The information of contacts you can pass in the body if you want, and can send email to account.